# Scope ID embedded in IPv4 mapped IPv6 addresses from getnameinfo()

Tags: ip-address, ipv6

Recently discovered a new behavior in a very recent linux distribution where `getnameinfo(..,NI_NUMERICHOST)` on a dualstack socket returns an IPv4 mapped IPv6 address WITH a scope identifier `::ffff:x.x.x.x%yyyyyyyyy` rather than `::ffff:x.x.x.x`

This new behavior has caused some breakage in existing applications which appear to be using string parsing to extract IPv4 addresses from IPv4 mapped IPv6 addresses.  No other operating system tested does this including slightly earlier versions of linux.

My understanding mapped addresses are to be treated as if they have global scope and hence should not have scope id's.  Moreover I have no clue what the point would be in intentionally doing this... scope ids don't exist in IPv4. Is this legitimate behavior or a regression in the network stack?

Comment: Can you please provide an actual code sample that illustrates the problem?

Comment: Is it a 169.254.0.0/16 address though?

Comment: They are globally routable addresses. It was not even RFC 1918 space.

Comment: More to the point, I don't think SO is the place to report Linux kernel bugs.